# AngularJS: how to prevent nested HTML from being compiled against a scope?

Tags: angularjs

Say I wanna have the `popup` directive with ability to declare it's content within a same HTML view:

```
<a popup>
    <span>Click me</span>

    <popup-content>
        <div with-some-other-directives></div>
    </popup-content>
</a>
```

I've tried:

- At popup directive, modify HTML during compile phase: get the content of the `<popup-content>...</popup-content>` element and then remove it completely. This way there are 2 problems:

  1. `with-some-other-directives` compiles and links.
  2. If I have an multiple `<a>` elements within `<popup-content>` I see some strange behavior. Suppose this has something to do with nesting an `<a>` inside an `<a>`.
- Making a separate `popup-content` directive, that has own compile phase handler. There, I could either access controller of parent `popup` directive and set the HTML there then self remove it.

Either way I get compilation and execution of `with-some-other-directives` directive.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. How to prevent HTML code within `<popup-content>` from being executed?
2. Are there better alternatives?

### EDIT

The final goal is to use HTML code taken from `popup-content`, compile it against the scope of `popup` directive and append to BODY.

Comment: That's what transclusion is for.

Comment: @zeroflagL I been thinking of this a lot of times, but cannot imagine how could I use it for this particular case

Comment: Transclusion does exactly what you tried with the difference that the content doesn't compile in the first place. So you can compile it later when you need to. It's a well documented feature.